# VIsio 2010 Can't 'see' File DSNs

Tags: sql-server-2008, datasource, reverse-engineering, visio, windows-7-x64

I'm using Visio 2010 Pro to reverse engineer my database. For some reason the wizard can't see my file dsns (I create them using the wizard) but System DSNs work fine. I'd like to make my DSN files portable so they can be shared with my team.

I've tried running Visio as administrator and have created umpteen file DNSs without success. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the exact same issue and I *believe* the issue is related to running a 32-bit version of Visio on a 64-bit machine. In my case, I was running a 32-bit version of Visio on a Windows 7 box. I had to go into the 64 bit ODBC dialogue directly (located here: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe) and create my connection, and then was able to go back into Visio and successfully connect. I believe what happens otherwise is you default to the 32 bit ODBC dialogue when creating your DSN in Visio, which then fails to show up when you are attempting to select your DSN later in the wizard process. This post touches on some additional detail regarding the 32-bit vs 64-bit nuances: http://robertoschiabel.wordpress.com/2008/02/28/windows-x64-32bit-odbc-vs-64bit-odbc/